# Validating yaml config file

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I want to have a configuration file in yaml format.

I want to have a configuration class in java that should be filled with the values of the file above.

I already found [Jackson](https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson) to pretty much exactly do this.

However I want to make sure that the file contains all values defined in the class. If I understand correctly, there is no direct way to ensure this using Jackson.

How do I detect if the file contains different (more/less/other) entries than expected by the class?

---

If I understand the answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813319/enforce-not-null-field-in-json-object) correctly, they suggest first reading the config file no matter what is inside and then trying to validate the resulting object, which might kind of work, but completely misses the point. I want tell the user "you forgot to add a line in your config" instead of "some field in my object is not set".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforce not-null field in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813319/enforce-not-null-field-in-json-object)

Comment: How does that question solve the problem?

Comment: Read through, including the accepted answer

Comment: @michas do you need only to validate that file contains all values defined in the class or some other validation as well? like correct strings formats or dates range?