# Get JSONException - Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

Normally, if a `key` doesn't exist in the response we created, Retrofit simply makes the variable null. I want to get `JSONException` if the key doesn't exist or something happens against the model we created. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: you will have to create a custom JSON deserializer for that.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12813319/6413377) might be one way.