# Converting a String to Json Object with validation in java

Tags: java, json, spring

I am having a string like ,

```
name = " {
        "Name" : "MyName"
      }"
```

and having a Model class like ,

```
 @Valid
    Class Model {
        @JsonProperty("Name")
        @Size(min = 1)
        @NotNull
        private String name;
    }
```

Now I am converting the string to Java Object by following code,

```
   Model name = objectMapper.readValue(name, Model.class);
```

So the validation(min = 1 and not null) is not happening with this.
How can I validate when I am converting a string to java object?

Comment: Can you show which annotation you use (`import` statement)?

Comment: import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

Comment: You have to use `@Valid` annotation on your class `Model`

Comment: @Andrey it's there in top of my class. I have updated the question.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133086/3636601) helps

Answer (score 1):

i will try to help u.

I have an idea and it´s that u divide the process in 2 parts:

First, u take the json and put in on a JSONObject:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
...
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(name);
```

Then, u can call, for example, a function passing a json that validate the values of json an if is correct return a model object:

```
public Model functionExample(JSONObject json){
     try{
          if(json.has("Name") && json.getString("Name")!=null){    
               return new Model(json.getString("Name"));         
          }
     }catch(Exception ex){
          return new Model();
     }
}
```

This check if the field "Name" exists and it´s not null.

I don´t know if it is what u want.

I hope it help u.